# Is there an android NDK linter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, linter

I inherited an android project that has a lot of stylistically messy C++ code.
I want to clean it up and enforce style consistency going forward.  Ideally I'd be able to specify a list of rules or a style guide that have to be followed.

Comment: `clang-format` is included with the NDK. Refer to [its documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for info on how to use it.